# DotNetOpenAuth 4 Sample MVC provider throws exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

I'm using the sample provider and relying party applications that come in the DotNetOpenAuth v4.0.0.12084 zip download and getting a protocol exception within the provider.

The web.config files provided in the samples don't appear to be valid as they try to use ASP.NET MVC 3 with .NET framework 3.5 (2). So I've updated them to use .NET framework 4.

These test URLs are unfortunately on my desktop and not available over the internet.

The provider is running on:
http://login.puffin.mediaburst.co.uk/

Relying party on:
http://testlogin.puffin.mediaburst.co.uk/

OpenID url used when logging in to the relying party:
http://login.puffin.mediaburst.co.uk/user/bob

I get the following error when submitting the OpenId using the relying party:

```
Error while reading message 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Messages.CheckIdRequest' 
parameter 'openid.claimed_id' with value 
'http://login.puffin.mediaburst.co.uk/user/bob'. 
Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Identifier'. 
(Contact: , Reference: )
```

I've enabled log4net and have put the provider logfile [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KHuxmdma)

To test the relying party I've authenticated against google and it works fine, suggesting the request format is correct.

Does anybody have any suggestions on stopping this invalid cast exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours is the second report for this bug.  I've filed [issue #109](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/issues/109) to track this.

Incidentally, I believe the samples are correct, since MVC 3 works fine on .NET 3.5, as far as I can tell.  Although [a known bug](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/issues/110) was that if MVC 4 is also installed on your machine that you build the samples on, they incorrectly bind to MVC 4 DLLs and result in a runtime failure.

Comment: Gah, it appears you're probably right about MVC 3 only targeting .NET 4.0.  Hmmm....

Comment: Hi Andrew, I've downloaded the new version of the samples and they work nicely, thanks for fixing the bug.